# Mesh Rendering based on distance

Tags: three.js

Is it somehow possible to filter rendered objects based on distance between camera and object ? I would like to specify that some object can be rendered only from close distance ( like details on complicated meshes etc ). I know i can handle this myself but before that I'm looking if there is any build in solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a feature is available for that. It is called level-of-detail ( LOD ).

See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lod.html. Click the mouse to see the effect.

three.js r.62